# hasOwnProperty is not a function in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am going to test if 'session' property exists:

```
console.log(queryData)
console.log(typeof queryData)
if ('session' in queryData) {
  console.log('in')
}
else {
  console.log('not in')
}
if (queryData.hasOwnProperty('session')) {
  console.log('has own propety')
}
```

Its result is:

```
[Object: null prototype] { session: '0geBdiCsfczLQiT47dd45kWVN2Yp' }
object
in
/home/ubuntu/22.enmsg/cli/main.js:72
  if (queryData.hasOwnProperty('session')) {
                ^

TypeError: queryData.hasOwnProperty is not a function
```

Why does the hasOwnProperty NOT work?

Comment: Because the object apparently does not have a prototype; that's what that "null prototype" message means.

Comment: How is `queryData` created?

Comment: @ChrisG let url = require('url'), then queryData = url.parse(req.url, true).query. It is the parsed result.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Most objects in javascript inherit from Object; it's possible to intentionally create objects that inherit from nothing (i.e., `null`), and therefore they won't have any of the typical methods you'd expect to live on the object.

You would normally know if your code was doing this, so the object might be something passed to you from another library.

A way around the error is to call `hasOwnProperty` on Object explicitly, and bind it to the object, like so:

```
// Calls "hasOwnProperty" on queryData, even if queryData has
// no prototype:
console.log(Object.hasOwnProperty.bind(queryData)('session'));
```

EDIT: Just editing to add an opinion, which is that a much better line for your purposes is the simple truthy check `if (queryData.session) {`. The vagueness of this check is a *strength* when what you're asking is "did a session get passed?" - if session is null, undefined, false, empty string, or the key is missing altogether, the answer is clearly "no".

Comment: While you can find lots of these truthy checks around, if the object has the given property but its value is zero [or true, or null] you'll get unexpected results.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution is to convert your null-prototype object to a standard javascript Object. You can do so by:

```
OBJjavascript = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objNullPrototype));
```

Answer (score 3):

Parsing the object as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56488323/3121906 would technically work but would be expensive for large objects.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53978289/3121906 is good, but why not just use `call`?

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(queryData, 'session')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is **a solution based on Optional chaining** I came up with. It works for anything I tested with and I do believe it's better (compared to the accepted answer), especially for large objects.

```
/**
 * Returns true if the specified parameter is an object 
 * that has the specified property defined
 * @param {any} propertyName Property name to check
 * @param {any} param Parameter to check
 * @return {boolean} true if param is an object containing 
 * the specified property or false otherwise
 */
hasProperty(propertyName, param) {
    const hasProperty = param?.hasOwnProperty?.(propertyName);
    return hasProperty !== undefined && hasProperty;
}
```