# The problem of sending files to the server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

there is a small form with an input to select a file and a button to send

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="fileInput" />
        <button type="button" onclick="uploadFile()">Send</button>
 </form>
```

function to send accordingly

```
 function uploadFile() {
          var input = document.getElementById("fileInput");
          var file = input.files[0];
          var formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("file", file);
  
          fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/fileupload", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
     
            },
          })
            .then((response) => {
              if (response.ok) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
              }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error( error);
            });
        }
```

there is a route for processing requests

```
const app = express();

const PORT = config.get("PORT");

app.use(fileUpload());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
// app.use("/api/auth", authRouter);
// app.use("/api/file", fileRouter);
app.use("/api/fileupload", (req, res) => {
  if (req.files && req.files.hasOwnProperty("file")) {
    const uploadedFile = req.files.file;
    console.log(uploadedFile.name)

  } else {
    res.status(400).send("File not found.");
  }
});

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(config.get("dbUrl"), {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log("port", PORT);
    });
  } catch (error) {}
};

start();
```

the problem is that the file is sent from the client side, but the server does not receive it. I use windows 10 + vs code

I have already looked at many options for implementing sending a file, I simplified the code to the simplest, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Are you using multer or similar middleware?

Comment: Have you maybe tried using `app.post` instead of `app.use` for the upload route, as `express-fileupload` documentation states? Also I don't think you need the explicit Content-type header, as it should be set by the browser with files boundary.

Comment: Express as it is won't handle multipart/form-data request bodies. You're supposed to employ a middleware for that specific purpose, such as Express/Multer.

Answer (score 0):

The request is not valid, you need to remove `Content-Type` header from the request.

Try this:

```
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/fileupload", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData
  })
```

see:

> Warning: When using FormData to submit POST requests using
> XMLHttpRequest or the Fetch_API with the multipart/form-data
> Content-Type (e.g. when uploading Files and Blobs to the server), do
> not explicitly set the Content-Type header on the request. Doing so
> will prevent the browser from being able to set the Content-Type
> header with the boundary expression it will use to delimit form fields
> in the request body.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Also, on the server, your check should throw an error, so in that case you need to change the property check:

```
  if (req.files && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(req.files, 'file')) {
```

see:
[hasOwnProperty is not a function in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53978067/hasownproperty-is-not-a-function-in-node-js)

or maybe simply:

```
if(req.files?.file)
```